# type special characters in android with sendStringSync api

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to type special characters use `sendStringSync`, but my `TextField` can't get characters with `onValueChange`.

```kotlin
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val inst = Instrumentation()
coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
   inst.sendStringSync(text)
}
```

```kotlin
@Compose
fun Text(){
   TextField(
    value = "",
    onValueChange = {Log.e(TAG, "$it")},
  )
}
```

how can I type special characters make onValueChange work

Comment: What value are you trying to type and how? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

To type special characters using the sendStringSync method and make the onValueChange callback work .

```
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val inst = Instrumentation()

@Preview
@Composable
fun Text() {
    val text = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            TextField(
                value = text.value,
                onValueChange = { newText ->
                    text.value = newText
                    Log.e(TAG, "$newText")
                },
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text),
                modifier = Modifier.height(56.dp).fillMaxWidth()
            )
        },
        update = { view ->
            coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                // Encode special characters before sending
                val encodedText = encodeSpecialCharacters(text.value)
                inst.sendStringSync(encodedText)
            }
        }
    )
}

// Function to encode special characters
fun encodeSpecialCharacters(text: String): String {
    // Encode special characters here
    // Replace special characters with their corresponding encoded values
    // Example: Replace '&' with '&amp;'
    return text
}
```